# How to draw phase portrait graph for nine system of differential equations in mathematica? Can have a code for darwing this?

Tags: differential-equations, graphs-and-networks

The differential equations for the transmission dynamics of HIV/AIDS are given as follows:

```
A'(t)=20+0.03*A(t)-0.00005*A(t)*Q(t)-0.0002*A(t)*Y(t)-0.0743*A(t),
B'(t)=0.03*B(t)+0.00005*A(t)*Q(t)+0.0002*A(t)*Y(t)-0.0743*B(t)-0.01072*B(t),
C'(t)=0.03*B(t)+0.00005*A(t)*Q(t)+0.0002*A(t)*Y(t)-0.0743*C(t)+0.01072*B(t),
P'(t)=15+0.03*P(t)-0.0001*P(t)*B(t)-0.0743*P(t),
Q'(t)=0.03*Q(t)+0.0001*P(t)*B(t)-0.0743*Q(t)-0.25*Q(t),
R'(t)=0.25*Q(t)-(0.0743+0.0123)*R(t)'
X'(t)=25-0.0003*X(t)*B(t)+0.03*X(t)-0.0743*X(t),
Y'(t)=0.0003*X(t)*B(t)-0.0743*Y(t)-0.35*Y(t),
Z'(t)=0.35*Y(t)-(0.0743+0.0123)*Z(t).
```

Here,

```
N(t)={A(t)+B(t)+C(t)+P(t)+Q(t)+R(t)+X(t)+Y(t)+Z(t)}
```

Plot the graph between `N(t)` and time `t`, `A(t)` and `B(t)`, `P(t)` and `Q(t)`, `X(t)`and `Y(t)`.

```
A(0)=150,B(0)=45,C(0)=10,P(0)=175,Q(0)=30,R(0)=15,X(0)=80,Y(0)=40,Z(0)=20


                                             (1)
```

Here,

Answer (score 3):

```
{af, bf, cf, pf, qf, rf, xf, yf, zf} = {a, b, c, p, q, r, x, y, z} /. 
NDSolve[{
 a'[t]==20+0.03*a[t]-0.00005*a[t]*q[t]-0.0002*a[t]*y[t]-0.0743*a[t], 
 b'[t]==0.03*b[t]+0.00005*a[t]*q[t]+0.0002*a[t]*y[t]-0.0743*b[t]-0.01072*b[t], 
 c'[t]==0.03*b[t]+0.00005*a[t]*q[t]+0.0002*a[t]*y[t]-0.0743*c[t]+0.01072*b[t],
 p'[t] == 15 + 0.03*p[t] - 0.0001*p[t]*b[t] - 0.0743*p[t], 
 q'[t] == 0.03*q[t] + 0.0001*p[t]*b[t] - 0.0743*q[t] - 0.25*q[t],
 r'[t] == 0.25*q[t] - (0.0743 + 0.0123)*r[t], 
 x'[t] == 25 - 0.0003*x[t]*b[t] + 0.03*x[t] - 0.0743*x[t], 
 y'[t] == 0.0003*x[t]*b[t] - 0.0743*y[t] - 0.35*y[t],
 z'[t] == 0.35*y[t] - (0.0743 + 0.0123)*z[t],
 a[0] == 150, b[0] == 45, c[0] == 10, p[0] == 175, q[0] == 30, 
 r[0] == 15, x[0] == 80, y[0] == 40, z[0] == 20},
 {a, b, c, p, q, r, x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100}][[1]];
n[t_]:=af[t]+bf[t]+cf[t]+pf[t]+qf[t]+rf[t]+xf[t]+yf[t]+zf[t];
Print[Plot[n[t], {t, 0, 100}]];
Print[ParametricPlot[{af[t], bf[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]];
Print[ParametricPlot[{pf[t], qf[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]];
Print[ParametricPlot[{xf[t], yf[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]];
```

Comment: you went to significant effort in transcribing equations and providing solution...I hope OP appreciates + 1 :-)

Comment: String convert everything to lower case, then ( to [, ) to ], = to == and that was most of it. At least his equations were sensible. If they were written out in prose or he had desktop published everything into Olde English Latex with Greek emoticons then it would have been much harder to make sure the answer was correct :)

Comment: Why do you wrap your plots in Print?

Comment: The reason I put those inside Print was because I thought I might be dealing with a novice user who might just scrape that into a single cell and evaluate it, didn't want to have to explain how to put each plot into a separate cell and didn't want to promote the sometimes risky style of leaving off semicolons. The Print forces the display of all the plots.